# Editing a UITableView with a TabBarButton from SJSegmentedViewController (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitabbar, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a view with SJSegmentedViewController for a custom navigation bar and I have added a custom edit on the navigation bar, The SJSegmentedViewController load UItableViews and I want when the user press the edit button to get the corresponding tableview to get into editing mode. Here is the code that I am using but I or I get error `Unexpectedly found nil` with `vc.viewDidLoad()` or it won't work, here is a link to the full project to you can test it: https://files.fm/f/xwduwmmt

SJSegmented View Code (NavViewController) :

```
 @IBAction func addButtClick(_ sender: UIButton) {


    let vc:ScheduleViewController =  ScheduleViewController()
    vc.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
    vc.editBoolean = true
    vc.viewDidLoad()


}
```

UITableView Code (ScheduleViewController) :

```
var editBoolean: Bool? = false

if (editBoolean == true) {
        self.ScheduleTableView.isEditing = true
    } else {
        self.ScheduleTableView.isEditing = false
    }
```

Comment: Just checked your project... it is not crashing anywhere. Can you try clean and build once?

Comment: hey, its not crashing because I did not add `vc.viewDidLoad() ` if you add it in `@IBAction func addButtClick(_ sender: UIButton) {` it will crash.

Comment: I will take a look at this, but let me start by saying you can't call viewDidLoad like that from another View Controller. That will always crash as it is a system function and it should only be called when the view is actually loaded.

Comment: Hey @CaseyWest took note of this tip, thanks!